# Is it possible to parametrise $x^{\frac{1}{x-1}}=y^{\frac{1}{y-1}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, parametric

I don't know if there is a process for parametrising $y^\frac{1}{y}=x^\frac{1}{x}$ and suspect it is not possible to do so. But if it is possible, is it also possible for the similar $x^{\frac{1}{x-1}}=y^{\frac{1}{y-1}}$? Furthermore, could the curve be isolated from the line $y=x$ observable in this [Wolfram|Alpha plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ecgiq1tjmqs)?

Comment: What type of parametrization are you looking for?  $x=t$, $y=t^{\frac{1}{t}}$ is a parametrization by normal definition and works perfectly fine.  Perhaps you meant $y^{\frac{1}{y}} = x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ as it is more "similar" to the second plot you mentioned.

Comment: Ugh yes, sorry, I did mean the latter, has been changed.

Comment: I don't understand the question of the body of the OP, but the answer to the question in the title is yes: the function $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{x-1}}$ is one-to-one on its domain, $(0,1)\cup(1,\infty)$, so $x^{\frac{1}{x-1}}=y^{\frac{1}{y-1}}$ implies that $y=x$. So, an obvious parametrization is $x=t$, $y=t$ with $t\in(0,1)\cup(1,\infty)$.

Comment: yeah, the $y=x$ is trivial, I'm looking for solutions where $y \ne x$.

Answer (score 0):

A parameterization
for
$y^\frac{1}{y}=x^\frac{1}{x}$
is well-known
(and not original by me).

Write it as
$x^y = y^x$
and let
$y = ry$.
Then
$x^{rx}=(rx)^x$.
Taking $x$-th roots,
$x^r = rx$.
Dividing by $x$,
$x^{r-1} - r$
or
$x = r^{\frac1{r-1}}$
and
$y 
= rx
= rr^{\frac1{r-1}}
= r^{1+\frac1{r-1}}
= r^{\frac{r}{r-1}}
$.

You might this
in your other equation
and see where it gets you.